# fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file > 'opencv_core300d.lib'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, opencv, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to run a multi project file from another developer. I am using a Mac computer with a Windows 7 bootcamp partition. I'm running the code on Visual Studios 2013 with OpenCV 3.0 and Qt.5.4.2.
(Im not sure if this affects the issue, but I have all these programs basically all on separate external USB drives because there isnt enough space on my partition)

The issue I think is that the original developer used Visual Studios 2012 and OpenCV 2.4.9.  In the files he gave to me, he included the necessary OpenCv files, but I installed OpenCV before realizing this and have tried to change the Config Properties to include the directory for the OpenCV 3.0.  Shouldn't this work?

The exact error is :

> LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file
>   'opencv_core300d.lib'

I'll also include Config Properties:

## **VC++ Directories**

*Executable Directories*: C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\bin;$(VCInstallDir)\bin\x86_amd64;$(VCInstallDir)\bin;$(ExecutablePath)

*Include Directories*: $(OPENCV_DIR)\build\include;$(IncludePath)

*Library Directories*:

C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\staticlib;C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib;E:\eyegaze\eyegaze\EyeGazeDemo;$(LibraryPath)

## **C/C++**

*Additional Include Directories*:

- ..\Libraries\OpenCV\include;
- C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2;->Changed to C:\opencv\build\include
- ..\Libraries\Intraface\include;
- $(QTDIR)\include;
- $(OPENCV_DIR)\include;
- $(QTDIR)\include\QtWidgets;
- $(QTDIR)\include\QtGui;
- $(QTDIR)\include\QtCore;
- debug;
- .;
- $(QTDIR)\mkspecs\win32-msvc2012;
- .\GeneratedFiles;
- %(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)

## **Linker**

### General

*Additional Library Directories*:

- $(OPENCV_DIR)\build\x64\vc12\staticlib;
- $(OPENCV_DIR)\build\x64\vc12\lib;
- $(QTDIR)\lib;
- E:\eyegaze\eyegaze\Libraries\OpenCV\lib;->removed
- E:\eyegaze\eyegaze\Libraries\Intraface\lib;
- E:\eyegaze\eyegaze\EyeGazeDemo;
- %(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)

  ### Input

*Additional Dependencies*:

- glu32.lib;
- opengl32.lib;
- gdi32.lib;
- user32.lib;
- $(QTDIR)\lib\qtmaind.lib;
- $(QTDIR)\lib\Qt5Cored.lib;
- $(QTDIR)\lib\Qt5Widgetsd.lib;
- $(QTDIR)\lib\Qt5Guid.lib;
- %(AdditionalDependencies);
- opencv_core300d.lib;
- opencv_imgproc300d.lib;
- opencv_highgui300d.lib;
- opencv_objdetect300d.lib;
- opencv_ml300d.lib;
- E:\eyegaze\eyegaze\Libraries\Intraface\lib\IntraFaceDLL-x86d.lib

Also I was wondering what is the difference between Configuration Properties->C/C++->Additional Include Directories and Configuration Properties->VC++ Directories->Include Directories?

Thank You in Advance!

## Update

I changed a few things in the configuration properties (noted above), and now the error is:

> 1>opencv_core249.lib(opencv_core249.dll) : fatal error LNK1112: module
>   machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'

My computer is x64 so I had changed all the settings for x64...
Im not sure If this made it worse, or if I fixed the problem?

Comment: sorry I will make you a silly question: Have you cheked the file is actually in the directory `$(OPENCV_DIR)\build\x64\vc12\lib`?

Comment: @RaydelMiranda Its actually not in that location, it is in $(OPENCV_DIR)\build\x64\vc12\staticlib. Do you think this would cause the error?

Comment: it definitely would !

Comment: Just a suggestion, since you say its a multiproject solution, Did u check if all the projects are compiled in `Debug` mode itself? Because even if a single project is built is `Release` mode, then you wont get `d` letter in the library files generated with the `*d.lib` name.

Comment: @Bharadwaj Im not sure if this is what you're asking, but when I build the whole solution, I have it set to Debug x64. And when I click on Config. Properties for each project, they're all on Debug

Comment: Also, did I need to download OpenCV, if all the needed files for it were given in the folder?

Comment: You better compile the library by the compiler you have. It is easy. What you need is CMake and Visual Studio Compiler.